# make a human-computer interaction interface

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I want do something I have to enter the commond in the terminal,that's very trouble.so I want to make a human-computer interaction interface, which have several buttons . Each button corresponds to a startup command that I always use. it's will better if I can enter some parameters. But I don't know what' technology I can use and also I don't have the  relevant data.
if someone konw something about this, please tell me. it 's nice if you can tell me some books or other messages which I can finish the task. Thank you very much !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207757/make-a-human-computer-interaction-interface/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are looking for something like this :

[dynamic_reconfigure.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14298818566592657.png)

this tutorial will help you:

http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/UsingTheDynamicReconfigurePythonClient

it creates a server that will publish in a topic if a change is entered in rqt

---

Originally posted by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) with karma: 170 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-04-24**:
thank you ,but I find this tourial  can only reconfigure one node's parameters. what I need is like this:when I press buttom A ,the node a will be launched,and then I press another button B, the node b will be launched.

**Comment by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) on 2015-04-24**:
mm maybe this one?

[rqt_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_launch)

You will need to make launchfiles of your nodes then

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-04-24**:
thank you very much ,that's may be what I need.